# sort and combine same text in file

Tags: bash

I have a `bash` that runs an `awk` that outputs a file like the one below:  Basically I am trying to combine matching `$2` values (text before the `-`) and output a combined sorted file.  The desired output is an example of the sorted/combined output I am trying to get.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr9:101906999-101907185 TPM1-1200|gc=63 281.2
chr2:21245693-21245924 APOB-279|gc=49.8 294.0
chr13:32903545-32903664 BRCA2-318|gc=27.7 30.2
chr19:55667932-55668051 TNNI3-2383|gc=55.5 161.8
chr2:21256161-21256400 APOB-288|gc=46 198.7
chr15:63353044-63353163 TPM1-1200|gc=63 481.2
```

**file_match**

```
TPM1
APOB
BRCA2
TNNI3
APOB
TPM1
```

**current output**

```
chr9:101906999-101907185 TPM1-1200|gc=63 281.2
chr2:21245693-21245924 APOB-279|gc=49.8 294.0
chr13:32903545-32903664 BRCA2-318|gc=27.7 30.2
chr19:55667932-55668051 TNNI3-2383|gc=55.5 161.8
chr2:21256161-21256400 APOB-288|gc=46 198.7
chr15:63353044-63353163 TPM1-1200|gc=63 481.2
```

**desired output**

```
chr9:101906999-101907185 TPM1-1200|gc=63 281.2
chr15:63353044-63353163 TPM1-1200|gc=63 481.2
chr2:21245693-21245924 APOB-279|gc=49.8 294.0
chr2:21256161-21256400 APOB-288|gc=46 198.7
chr13:32903545-32903664 BRCA2-318|gc=27.7 30.2
chr19:55667932-55668051 TNNI3-2383|gc=55.5 161.8
```

**bash that produces the current output**

```
logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/process.log
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/bedtools/*base_counts.txt ; do (input)
 echo "Start custom panel creation: $(date) - File: $f"
 bname=$(basename $f)
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
 awk '
 NR == FNR {input[$0]; next}
 {
 split($5, a, "-")
 if (a[1] in input) {
     key = $4 OFS $5
     n[key]++
     sum[key] += $7
 }
 }
 END {
 for (key in n) 
     printf "%s %.1f\n", key, sum[key]/n[key]
}
' file_match $f > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/2-12-2015/bedtools/${pref}_Incidentalcoverage.bed
 echo "End custom panel creation: $(date) - File: $f"
done >> "$logfile"
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a description and example output. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: I added a line that asks how to sort/combine by matching `$2` values.  The script does run I just need to format the output.  Thank you :).

Comment: what will be the sorting order?  I don't see the values sorted in the desired output (Txxx, Txxx, Axxx, Axxx, Bxxx, Nxxxx).

Comment: Can you post an example of the input files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without changing the current script (since there is no input file to verify correctness), you can pipe the output to this to sort on the prefix on second field.

```
$ ... | awk '{split($2,a,"-"); print a[1] "\t" $0}' | sort | cut -f2-

chr2:21245693-21245924 APOB-279|gc=49.8 294.0
chr2:21256161-21256400 APOB-288|gc=46 198.7
chr13:32903545-32903664 BRCA2-318|gc=27.7 30.2
chr19:55667932-55668051 TNNI3-2383|gc=55.5 161.8
chr15:63353044-63353163 TPM1-1200|gc=63 481.2
chr9:101906999-101907185 TPM1-1200|gc=63 281.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your current script to this single `sort` command, based on version:

```
./script.sh | sort -k2,2V
```

**Output:**

```
chr2:21245693-21245924 APOB-279|gc=49.8 294.0
chr2:21256161-21256400 APOB-288|gc=46 198.7
chr13:32903545-32903664 BRCA2-318|gc=27.7 30.2
chr19:55667932-55668051 TNNI3-2383|gc=55.5 161.8
chr15:63353044-63353163 TPM1-1200|gc=63 481.2
chr9:101906999-101907185 TPM1-1200|gc=63 281.2
```